# Matlab test runner skips test functions that try to import non-existing file

Tags: matlab

Let's define a simple test class

```
classdef test_file < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods(Test)
        function test_function(testCase)
            import some_package.some_function
            testCase.verifyEqual(true,some_function(0));    
        end
    end
end
```

It is irrelevant what `some_function` does. Function some_package.some_function does not exist in my path (for example I forgot to add it when pushing a commit). Whenever I try to run the test file above the test `test_function` is skipped with warning:

```
Warning: "test_file.m" was excluded.
Caused by:
    Error: File: test_file.m Line: 4 Column: 20
    The import statement 'import sc_force_models.apparent_accel' cannot be found or cannot be imported. Imported names must
    end with '.*' or be fully qualified.
```

Since the test is skipped the problem is undetected and test runner returns 0 errors. In case someone forgets to commit a file I'd still like to detect this problem during testing, so expected behavior is to fail the test case.

As a workaround I've tried using the 'Strict',True argument to testrunner but it neither detects the issue. I've also tried putting the import statement between `try`, `catch` statements but it seems any code in the file is not executed.

Any ideas how to detect incorrect import statements in test cases?